# Dual of squared hinge objective

Tags: convex-optimization, duality-theorems

I want to find the dual of squared hinge objective. I know it must be similar to dual of $\text{SVM}$ formulation, wanted to double confirm how this will be calculated.

$$\min_{w,b}\sum_{i=1}^{M}[\max(0, 1-y_{i}(w^{T}x_{i}+b))]^{2}+\lambda||W||^{2}.$$

I went through Bishop and Deisenroth's book. These [notes](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Ewelling/teaching/KernelsICS273B/SVregression.pdf) from Max welling are also helpful but all of them discuss linear cases. Here's where I'm stuck:

$\dfrac{1}{2}||w||^{2}-\sum_{i=1}^{M}2\alpha_{i}[y_{i}(w^{T}x_{i}+b)-1](y_{i}x_{i})$ such that $\alpha_{i}>0$. How to extract $w$ from here ?

Comment: [A Study on L2-Loss (Squared Hinge-Loss) Multi-Class SVM](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/l2mcsvm/l2mcsvm.pdf)

Comment: Its kind of a different forumulation. Not the one I'm looking for.

Comment: It's almost identical, the differences are negligible and doing an adaptation is very simple. You planned not to do any work yourself?

Comment: I saw the PDF carefully, how to formulate this problem (squared hinge loss) like the PDF shows to the objective shown in PDF ?